# list comprehension squaring odds

Tags: python

This is what I am supposed to do:

> Given the variable `nums`, whose value is a list of integers, write an assignment statement that assigns to the variable `square_odds` the list of the squares of the odd numbers in the list `nums`.
>
> You must use list comprehension.

Here is what I have so far, I know the range part is wrong but what is it supposed to look like?

```
nums = [2 ** square_odds for square_odds in range(nums) if square_odds != x%2]
```

I think there are other places that are wrong but I am not sure.

i changed it to

```
nums = [square_odds**2 for square_odds in range(100) if square_odds%2 != 0]
```

i received the message

Wrong: you have not assigned to square_odds.

Comment: What is `x` there at the end? And that is how you square a number as you are doing at the beginning? Seems like you need some `Mathematics` first.

Comment: Where are you using it exactly?

Comment: You misunderstood the assignment completely. `nums` is a list of numbers, `square_odds` should be a list of the squares of all odd numbers in `nums`. So it makes no sense to assign to nums or iterate over `range(nums)` - you need to iterate over `nums` directly.

Comment: You're putting the result in the variable `nums`.  The instructions say you need to "assign[] to the variable **square_odds** the list of the squares of the odd numbers in the list nums."

Answer (score 2):

Also, since nums is already a list do not use range(nums). Range returns a list given start and stop values. Iterate through your list nums in this way (part of your list comprehension):

```
[SQUARING OPERATION HERE  for num in nums MODULO TEST HERE]
```

since this is homework I won't write it all out.

Answer (score 1):

- To test whether a number is odd or not, you need to take its modulus with `2` and test it whether its 0 or not.
  So, if `num % 2 != 0`, then your `num` is `odd`
- To square a given number, you do: - `number ** 2` and **not** `2 ** number`
- You also have a `3rd` argument in `range` function, that denotes the `step-value`. You can use that`(range(1, last_num, 2))` to get just the `odd` number. That way you won't need a `modulus` operator.

You can do the above changes to get your list-comprehension work.

Given your question, where `nums` is already a list of numbers, you need to use just `nums` rather than `range(nums)` like this: -

```
nums = [square_odds**2 for square_odds in nums if square_odds%2 != 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = [square_odds**2 for square_odds in range(nums) if square_odds%2 != 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution?

```
square_odds=[i*i for i in filter(lambda x:x&1,nums)]
```